# Upper bound for "parallel bubbling "

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

What would be an upper bound for a sort algorithm that does the following?

One pass would look like this: An element looks at its successor and if the successor is bigger they swap. If an element was swapped during a pass, it can't swap again.
For example `[2,3,5,5] -> [3,2,5,5]`

How many passes is the worst case? It can't possibly be n like bubble sort I believe as there is the condition that an element is blocked from swapping more than once in the same pass?

Comment: So if the array is [3,2,1], which elements swap in the 1st pass?

Comment: That would be a sorted array @MattTimmermans. It is sorting in desc order. If it would be in ascending order then the array would be [2,3,1] after the first pass.

Comment: So the rule is that if an element's predecessor needs to swap, then it doesn't get to swap?

Comment: Yes, if an element was part of a swap then it doesn't get to swap again @MattTimmermans

Comment: That's a little different, but OK.  When you say "doesn't get to swap again", you are assuming the the swaps are ordered from the start toward the end, but that is not "parallel".

Comment: How can the input array [1,2,3] after first pass be [2, 3, 1]. You cannot swap 1 with 3, as it was swapped with 2, correct? @user737163